# How to find duplicates in a linked list?

Tags: c, linked-list

```
void duplicates()
{
    int count=0;
    struct node *temp=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp=head;
    struct node *temp1=(struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    temp1=head;
while(temp!=NULL)
{
    while(temp1!=NULL)
    {
        if(strcmp(temp->FN,temp1->FN)==0)
        {

            count++;
        }
        temp1=temp1->next;
    }
    if(count>1)
    {
        printf("DUPLICATE FOUND: %s",temp->FN);
    }
    count=0;
    temp=temp->next;
}
}
```

I'm trying to find duplicates from a linked list and can't find it with my function, I have checked to see that the linked list has all the data stored with a print() function so I think the problem lies in my logic to find the duplicates. 
Thank You

Comment: `if(count>1)` - so one duplicate does not count?

Comment: The matching logic looks fine, but why are you `malloc`ing memory for `temp` and `temp1` and then replacing it with `head`?

Comment: Please think of what happens when `temp1` becomes `NULL` and right after `temp=temp-next`, and please learn to use a debugger, or at least use `printf` to print where your logic is going.

Comment: @EugeneSh. According to my code there will always be one instance where count increases to 1 when temp is comparing the same node with temp1.

Comment: Also note that if you are starting at the same location you will have the case where you compare `temp==temp1` that is why I would recommend setting `temp1=temp->next`

Comment: @ChrisTurner Apologies for the error, in my code head is also a temporarily allocated pointer of type struct node.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've missed one crucial line from your code (or rather put it in the wrong place).

When you've looped through the inner loop, you never reset `temp1` to point back to the start of the list again.

```
void duplicates()
{
    int count=0;
    struct node *temp;
    struct node *temp1;
    temp=head;
    while(temp!=NULL)
    {
        temp1=head;
        count=0;
        while(temp1!=NULL)
        {
            if(strcmp(temp->FN,temp1->FN)==0)
            {

                count++;
            }
            temp1=temp1->next;
        }
        if(count>1)
        {
            printf("DUPLICATE FOUND: %s",temp->FN);
        }
        temp=temp->next;
    }
}
```

You don't need to allocate memory for either `temp` or `temp1` as they'll be pointing at memory allocated for your list.

I've also moved the resetting of `count=0` to before the inner loop as it makes sense to prepare things before the inner loop rather than resetting them afterwards.